# get site name along with protocol in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

How can I get current site name with it's used protocol in **laravel**?

For example suppose user requested this :

```
https://example.com/some/path
```

I want to get `https://example.com` in a controller method.

**Update:**

I used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) service to access my localhost as a `https` random domain that it provieded and in all ways that suggested in answers returned main `http://localhost`

Comment: for site url below post is correct. for request method use `$request->method`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
request()->root()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use this function.

```
url('/');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getSchemeAndHttpHost()` method:

```
request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()
```